# Widget Kicks Off Main Activity Unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

I have a widget application that includes a Main application widget registered as below,
clicking on the widget sometimes launches the app activity when I have no such intention.
What can be done to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Could you please post the code that is causing the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: Well its just a regular widget but inside the manifest I have registered an activity.  That activity has a filter like this:  <intent-filter>
                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: I call startService from the widget but thats all.

Comment: I removed the filter and it no longer occurs, but it seems like  I should be able to keep a Main activity in the app that the widget?

Comment: No the service does sometimes launch activities to do tasks other than main activity, maybe this could be causing it.  Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the main activity's definition in your manifest 
as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535673/why-does-starting-an-activity-from-a-widget-cause-my-main-activity-to-start-as-we/4540799#4540799).

`<activity

android:name=".YourActivity"

 android:launchMode="singleInstance" ...`