# Clicking Widget mistakenly causes main Activity to launch

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

Widget Launches the Applications Main Activity unexpectedly.  Should I just not have a Main activity when I have an app that hosts a widget?  Not clear why it launches, but this is not the behavior I want.  I want no activities to Launch unless they are specifically requested by intent to do so?

Comment: Post your code.  It sounds like you are setting a pending intent on the widget to open your activity.  This doesn't just happen by default.

Comment: I removed any reference to the Activity and it still happens. I believe this is because the Activity is the main activity of the applciation.  And when I do run methods on the service hosted by the application it brings the app up to the top again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the main activity's definition in your manifest 
as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535673/why-does-starting-an-activity-from-a-widget-cause-my-main-activity-to-start-as-we/4540799#4540799).

`<activity

android:name=".YourActivity"

 android:launchMode="singleInstance" ...`