# My notification service starts Main activity if my app has been minimised by pressing the home button

Tags: android

My app has a notification service. The problem is when my app has been minimised [by pressing the home button] and notification service fires a notification my main activity gets started on its own. Its really annoying and i need to fix it.

Any one with a probable solution??

I tried using android:launchMode="singleInstance" given as a solution @ [Why does starting an activity from a widget cause my main activity to start as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535673/why-does-starting-an-activity-from-a-widget-cause-my-main-activity-to-start-as-we/4540799#4540799) but the problem with this solution is that if i try to re-start my app using the "long press home button, which gives the list of recently used app" my app never runs.

In order to re-run it then i have to go to my App's Icon in menu and open it from there.

Is there a way i can solve both these problems??

Activity that generates notification :

package org.example.com;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ParentActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_copy);

    NotificationManager newNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Notification notificationDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"Downloads available!!",System.currentTimeMillis());
    notificationDetails.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this,ParentActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("IS_FOREGROUND",1);
    //newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent newPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, newIntent, 0);

    CharSequence contentTitle = "Downloads Available!!";
    CharSequence contentText  = "Some new Downloads are available, click to enable.";
    int notificationId = 3;

    notificationDetails.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, newPendingIntent);
    newNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationDetails);

    finish();

}
}
```

Comment: you can not control the behaviour of home button...

Comment: What should your application do when a notification is fired?

Comment: @ vineetska : I dont want to control the behaviour of home button, all i want is a way by which my notification service doesnt starts my minimised app.

Comment: @Zoleas : Service periodically fires "SOMETHING XYZ UPDATED" notification, but when user is using the app and has minimised the app for a while, say for text messaging etc, the notification service fires a notification and also it brings the Target activity of notification mentioned in <code>Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TargetActivity.class); </code> to foreground.

This only happens when app is minimised. But it works well when the app is not running i.e. it correctly shows the notification only.

Comment: Can you post the code wich creates the notification?

Comment: I have edited the post and added the Activity that generates notifications.

Comment: @Zoleas I have added the code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your code that your are in an activity, that's why your application come to the foreground I think. Does your service start this activity?
If it is a service that fires the notification, why not creating the notification in that service? Then your application will stay in the background.

Comment: I have other stuff in this activity as well which requires it to be made an activity.. So what can be other alternatives?

Comment: Yeah but what I mean is : Has this activity to be launched when your service fires your "notification"? If you launch this activity, you will have something on the screen. If you want to do just background tasks (like creating a notification in the status bar) use a service instead.

Comment: My activity shows an alert dialog if user is using the app, if user is not using the app then notifications about updates are shown.

This alert dialog has some confirmatory messages and all...

My activity only fires when app is minimised by pressing home button... when app is not running service only fires notifications and doesnot starts activity... I have been working on it since 3 days...

Comment: You may consider to change your application behaviour. What about allways showing only the notification in the status bar and not starting an activity? You still can start your activity and display your popup when the user taps the notification.

Comment: Thanks Zoleas, i used notifications in my service and for other things a conditional check starts the activity [if need be]